# Angular js Tables no muestra filas

Tags: angularjs

estoy empezando con una tabla de ordenación y filtro automático con Angular. Quiero usar [ng-table](http://ng-table.com/#/)

El caso es que por más que pruebo no consigo que la app muestre filas, me sale el formato de las tablas con sus dos campos de entrada para los filtros, pero no muestra filas..

A continuación el código

```
<body ng-app="main">
```

...

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="usuariosController as users">
                <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
                    <tr ng-repeat="user in users.data">
                        <td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
                            {{user.name}}</td>
                        <td title="'Age'" filter="{ age: 'number'}" sortable="'age'">
                            {{user.age}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

....

```
        (function () {
        'use strict';

        var myApp = angular.module('main', ['ngTable']);

        myApp.controller('usuariosController', function (NgTableParams) {


            var self = this;
            var data = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                {name: "Simon", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Christian", age: 34},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27}];
                self.tableParams = new NgTableParams({ count: 5}, { counts: [5, 10, 25], dataset: data});

            ;
        });
    })();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien, he encontrado una solución. Para quien le interese, puede ver el siguiente [codepen](https://codepen.io/DeividasK/pen/qrWqey?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

Se soluciona con inyectar $scope dentro de la parte de la función del controlador, para que puedas usar correctamente en la vista el ng-repeat. De esta forma `<tr ng-repeat="user in $data">` y teniendo tu controlador asi :

`var app = angular.module("MyApp", ["ngTable"]);`

`app.controller('usuariosController', function ($scope, NgTableParams) {
  var self = this;
  var data = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                {name: "Simon", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Christian", age: 34},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27}];
  self.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, { dataset: data });`

 `console.log(self.tableParams)
});`